# 'Simple' Calculator - C# (Set focus on text box 2...)

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

To give you all a bit of my programming background, I'm a first year Software Engineering Student (started this academic year). I've been programming for the best part of a year, mainly using HTML and Python. The language I will be using throughout my degree is C#. (I'm still fairly new to this programming language) and the IDE being used is Visual Studio 2013.

As I've literally just started my course 3 weeks ago, I was given a task to do. It was to create a simple calculator which can add, subtract, multiply, divide various numbers from user input. This I have done, as well as implementing a way for users to do maths with floating points.

In order to make the calculator a bit more user friendly, I decided to add number buttons, based on the layout of the Windows Calculator. It has two input text boxes and one output text box which allows users to copy and then paste their answer into other documents etc. I've only got 4 operator buttons which are; +,-,*,/. In addition, I also added an 'Exit' button.

Whenever the user inputs the two values, they have to press one of the operator buttons. For example; if the user types in **10** in **'txtNum1'** and **20** in **'txtNum2'** and presses **'btnAdd'**, the value of the sum will be represented in **'txtAnswer'**.

(I would provide an image of the form but I require at least 10 reputation points on this website, so apologies in advance)

The issues which I'm having with the form are;
- I can only input values into one text box (using the mouse + available buttons on screen). I've tried using boolean in order to check whether '**Focus**' has been set to a particular box and then going from there but I'm completely lost on what to do next. My lecturer actually advised me to use this boolean method in order to help solve the issue.

Any advice is greatly appreciated + I would appreciate it if you guys taught me a better way of representing my code, maybe reduce the amount by using functions etc. I'm always keen to learn new tips + tricks.

Here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AddUpNums
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Boolean ff;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void checkForEmptySpace()
        {
            if (txtNum1.Text == "")
                txtNum1.Text = "0";
            if (txtNum2.Text == "")
                txtNum2.Text = "0";
        }

        private void btnAddUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkForEmptySpace();
            double num1, num2, sum;
            num1 = double.Parse(txtNum1.Text);
            num2 = double.Parse(txtNum2.Text);
            sum = num1 + num2;
            txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);

        }

        private void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkForEmptySpace();
            double num1, num2, sum;
            num1 = double.Parse(txtNum1.Text);
            num2 = double.Parse(txtNum2.Text);
            sum = num1 - num2;
            txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }

        private void btnMultiply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkForEmptySpace();
            double num1, num2, sum;
            num1 = double.Parse(txtNum1.Text);
            num2 = double.Parse(txtNum2.Text);
            sum = num1 * num2;
            txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }

        private void btnDivide_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkForEmptySpace();
            double num1, num2, sum;
            num1 = double.Parse(txtNum1.Text);
            num2 = double.Parse(txtNum2.Text);
            sum = num1 / num2;
            txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
        }

        private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //txtNum2.Focus();
            //if (txtNum2.Focus() == true)
            //   txtNum2.Text += "0";
            //if (txtNum1.Focus() == true)
            //   txtNum1.Text += "0";


        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtNum1.Text += "1";
            if (ff)
                txtNum2.Text += "1";

        }

        private void txtNum1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void txtNum2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            ff = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still new to C# so go easy on me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A boolean will work like you've described.  Just flag it when the user clicks in either textbox:

```
private void txtNum1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ff = false;
}

private void txtNum2_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   ff = true;
}
```

Now, if `ff` is false, you want to write to `txtNum1`, and `txtNum2` if `ff` is true.

For the number buttons, I'd write one `Click` event, then wire all 10 of your number buttons up to it

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(ff)
      txtNum2.Text += (sender as Button).Text;       
   else       
      txtNum1.Text += (sender as Button).Text;       
}
```

Assuming each Button's text is simply `1`, `2`, etc.

In trying to reduce your code, you can see that each operation's function is pretty much identical, except one line.  That's a pretty good sign that you can refactor:

```
private void btnOperator_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkForEmptySpace();
    double num1, num2, sum;
    num1 = double.Parse(txtNum1.Text);
    num2 = double.Parse(txtNum2.Text);

    double result = 0;
    switch((sender as Button).Name)
    {
       case "btnSubtract":
          result = num1 - num2;
          break;
       case "btnAdd":
          //...
    }  

    txtAnswer.Text = Convert.ToString(sum);
}
```

Comment: I would recommend against using the `Click` event in favor of using the `GotFocus` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: It's been a while since I've made a winforms app.  You're probably right @CodingGorilla

Comment: I want to kiss you right now. Thank you so much!! I've been trying to figure this out all day! Again, much thanks for the swift reply + help, truly appreciated :D You've helped me out a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there a way for the user to swap back to 'txtNum1' after they've already 'in-putted' a value into 'txtNum2'?

Comment: Check the `TabIndex` and `TabStop` properties of your textboxes. It will allow you to use the TAB key properly to switch between them.

Comment: they should just have to click on either textbox and they'll be able to write to it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the Enter event because this is where the control gains focus. Here is some sample code that may help out:

```
private void OnEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == this.textBox1)
        {
            if (this.textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = "0";

                if (textBox2.Text == "0")
                    this.textBox2.Text = "";

            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (this.textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                this.textBox2.Text = "0";

                if (textBox1.Text == "0")
                    this.textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Then all you would have to do to apply the event to your textboxes is this:

```
textBox1.Enter += OnEnter;
textBox2.Enter += OnEnter;
```

I also agree with [Jonesy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1786428/jonesy) that you should work on abstracting your code to promote reusability.